# Backup of Redmine files

Tags: backup, redmine

Does anyone know how to take a backup of Redmine files. My files are located at `/data/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/files`. I need to get them in a folder of `.tgz`. Is it possible? If yes please tell me the command also to unzip it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean the attatchments??????????????

If yes use `-tar -pzcf $BACKUP_DIR/${DATE}/redmine_files.tar.gz -C $REDMINE_HOME`

You need to specify the `BACKUP_DIR`and `REDMINE_HOME` in your script.And please make a script according to your need and schedule in a `crontab` if you need it regurly.

Use `tar zxvf redmine_files.tar.gz` for unzipping.

Comment: user3400717: I need this in a regular basis?Which crontab entries needs to be entered?

Comment: You should write a shell script `backup-redmine.bash` which wraps the above invocation of `tar(1)` command, and then simply call it from crontab: `10 3 * * * /path/to/backup-redmine.bash` (3:10 am, for example)